# Insert multiple rows to index

Tags: python, pandas, insert

I'm looking for a concise way of inserting rows in the middle of a `DataFrame` so that the rows after the insertion point are pushed forward. It would look something like this:

```
Data Frame A      Data Frame B
Idx | C1 | C2     Idx | C1 | C2 
----+----+----    ----+----+----
 0  | 12 | 31      0  | 49 | 67 
 1  | 64 | 98      1  | 25 | 63 
 2  | 47 | 10

Inserting B to A[2]:
Idx | C1 | C2
----+----+----
 0  | 12 | 31
 1  | 64 | 98
 2  | 49 | 67     # B[0]
 3  | 25 | 63     # B[1]
 4  | 47 | 10
```

This would have to be done for multiple data frames, or rather slices of the original. There's always the option of looping through with `pd.concat` and the slice and insert indices, but for a library like `pandas` I'd expect someone to already have come up with an answer I haven't come across.

`append` doesn't quite work, but it's close. There actually exists `df.insert`, but it's for columns. I'd appreciate any pointers even to helpful documentation.

#### Sandbox:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
b = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5], [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is just to slice and concatenate:

```
insertion_point = 2

pd.concat([a.iloc[:insertion_point], b, a.iloc[insertion_point:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  5  6
4  3  4
```

Comment: This works well with the multiple slices I have. Not optimal, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Let `i` be the position of insertion. `i` refers to the exact position, not based on the index

```
df = A.loc[:i]
df.append(B,ignore_index = True)
df.append(A.loc[i:],ignore_index=True)
```

`df` is your desired dataframe